# Add package markdown to autogenerated package

Tags: front-end, packages

I develop in .nb files and autogenerate my packages from them (by setting the notebook option `AutoGeneratedPackage -> Automatic`) and have no desire to change this, as with the right style settings (crucially `InitializationGroup`) and some block-indentation code it's very comfortable and easy to toggle from testing to development.

Unfortunately one issue is that I lose the nice package markdown that comes from editing in .m files. I'm able to strip the ugly package header by messing with `FrontEndResourceString["PackageHeader"]`, but I don't have a way to reinstate the markdown.

*To see the markdown, edit the .m file using Mathematica by adding Section/Subsection etc. cells. Then, view the saved .m file in a regular text editor.*

Is there a way?

I know I can do something hacky like generate it myself via `ExportAutoReplacements`, e.x. set

```
{
  "\[LeftDoubleBracket]"->"(* ::Section:: *)\n(*",
  "\[RightDoubleBracket]"->"*)"
 }
```

or whatever, but this is just so much more unwieldy than whatever internal thing they must use to generate the markdown.

Comment: How exactly do you autogenerate packages from NB files? Using [`File ► Save As…`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/SaveAs.html)?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov `AutoGeneratedPackage` (Although the two probably work pretty much the same. I should see if there's a packet or token there I can make work for me.)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I use `InitializationGroup` for the added flexibility. (it makes debugging easier when I can uncomment a code block by simply adding a higher priority group)

Comment: What do you mean by `InputGroup`? `CellGroupingRules->"InputGrouping"`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov that is just a mistake. It should be `InitializationGroup`. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fairly long answer describing a method to achieve your goals using a stylesheet and a custom [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox).

***[`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox)***

The following is a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) that exports the way you want. For example:

```
TemplateBox[
    {"section heading", "Section"},
    "Markup",
    DisplayFunction -> (#&),
    InterpretationFunction -> (
        Cell@TextData[{"(* ::", #2, ":: *)\n(*", Cell[BoxData[#]], "*)"}]&
    )
]
```

This [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) will display as `section heading`, but will copy as `(* ::Section:: *)\n(*section heading*)` when a notebook containing this [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) autogenerates a package file. For example, evaluating the following:

```
CreateDocument[
    {
    Cell[
        BoxData @ TemplateBox[
            {"section heading", "Section"},
            "Markup",
            DisplayFunction -> (#&),
            InterpretationFunction -> (
                Cell@TextData[{"(* ::", #2, ":: *)\n(*", Cell[BoxData[#]], "*)"}]&
            )
        ],
        "Section",
        Evaluatable->True,
        System`InitializationGroup -> True
    ]
    },
    AutoGeneratedPackage -> Automatic
];
```

and then saving the resulting notebook will create an autogenerated package with a `Section` cell.

**Section Appearance**

Next, we need to make the output look more like it is supposed to (font/color), and we need to have some automated way of using the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox). The following enhancement to the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) takes care of font/color:

```
TemplateBox[
    {"section heading", "Section"},
    "Markup",
    DisplayFunction -> (StyleBox[#,
        FontFamily -> CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, #2, FontFamily}],
        FontColor -> CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, #2, FontColor}]
    ]&),
    InterpretationFunction -> (
        Cell@TextData[{"(* ::", #2, ":: *)\n(*", Cell[BoxData[#]], "*)"}]&
    )
]
```

*Mangled TemplateBox Issue*

One final comment about this [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox). If the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) is at the top level, then the markup in the [`InterpretationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpretationFunction) will be correctly exported to the autogenerated package. However, if the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) is not at the top level, then things will go wrong. For example, a structure like:

```
Cell[
    BoxData @ RowBox[{
        TemplateBox[{"stuff", "Section"}, "Markup"],
        "more stuff"
    }],
    "Section"
]
```

where I've removed some extraneous stuff, will produce an empty `Section` cell, and a code cell with `(*stuff*)more stuff`.

For this reason, it will be very useful if the `ExportedSection` cell has a visible marker for content outside of the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox).

***StyleKeyMapping***

Now, I'm going to show a [`StyleKeyMapping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleKeyMapping) approach to automating the use of the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox). An example of a [`StyleKeyMapping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleKeyMapping) can be found in the `Input` style:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Input", StyleKeyMapping}]
```

{"Tab" -> "Code", "=" -> "WolframAlphaShort", "*" -> "Item"}

When the insertion point in an `Input` cell is placed at the very beginning of the cell, entering <kbd>TAB</kbd> will convert the `Input` cell into a `Code` cell. Similarly, entering <kbd>=</kbd> will convert to a [`WolframAlpha`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha) query cell, and <kbd>*</kbd> will convert to an `Item` cell.

**ExportedSection Style**

For my purposes, in a `Section` cell, I want <kbd>TAB</kbd> to convert the cell into an `ExportedSection` cell, that has the right properties for a cell to be included in the autogenerated package. Here is an example of an `ExportedSection` cell style:

```
Cell[StyleData["ExportedSection", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Section"]],
    StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"FromExport"},
    Evaluatable->True,
    System`InitializationGroup->True,
    Background->GrayLevel[.95],
    FontColor->RGBColor[0,.5,.0]
]
```

Some explanation:

1. `StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Section"]` will inherit styles from the `Section` style.
2. I've included a [`StyleKeyMapping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleKeyMapping) to revert to a normal `Section` style. I will explain later why I don't just use `"[`Tab`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tab)" -> "Section"`.
3. `Evaluatable->True` is needed so that the cell is included in the autogenerated package.
4. `InitializationGroup->True` is also needed so that the cell is included in the autogenerated package. The reason I use `` System`InitializationGroup `` is because the [`InitializationGroup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InitializationGroup) symbol doesn't exist in a fresh kernel.
5. Background->`GrayLevel[.95]` is used to indicate that the cell will be included in the autogenerated package.
6. Earlier I discussed how things will go wrong if there is content outside of the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox). By giving the `ExportedSection` style a font color of green, content outside the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) will be green, while content inside the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) is controlled by the [`FontColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontColor) of the [`DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction). This makes it easy to see when the `ExportedSection` style is mangled and will not export well.

**CellDynamicExpression**

Now, we are finally ready to discuss how to insert the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) (at the top level) into an `ExportedSection` cell. There is a [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) option, [`CellDynamicExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellDynamicExpression):

```
WolframLanguageData["CellDynamicExpression", "PlaintextUsage"]
```

"CellDynamicExpression is an option for cells that specifies an expression to \
be dynamically updated whenever the cell is visible on screen."

We can use [`CellDynamicExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellDynamicExpression) in the style that is created when the [`StyleKeyMapping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleKeyMapping) takes place. I will use the RHS of the [`CellDynamicExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellDynamicExpression) to wrap the contents of the cell in the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox).

Now, I'm very concerned about having [`CellDynamicExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellDynamicExpression) active in a cell, because a continually triggering [`CellDynamicExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellDynamicExpression) will have unwanted effects. So, I will not have the `Section` style map to `ExportedSection` directly. Instead, I will map it to a `ToExportedSection` style, which will then use [`CellDynamicExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellDynamicExpression) to create a new cell with style `ExportedSection` and with the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) in the right place.

By the way, I really wanted to have just a `ToExport` style that automatically creates the right kind of cell when used as the target in [`StyleKeyMapping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleKeyMapping), but unfortunately, the new cell that is created has no indication of the previous style of the cell. So, I will need to create a `ToExportedXXX` style for each kind of cell style that I want to have exported.

**ToExportedSection**

Here is a prototype of the `ToExportedSection` style:

```
Cell[StyleData["ToExportedSection",StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Section"]],
    CellDynamicExpression :> With[
        {
        content = func[NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]]]
        },

        NotebookWrite[
            EvaluationCell[],
            content,
            All
        ];
        SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],After,CellContents];
        SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Previous,Character]
    ],
    DefaultFormatType->InputForm
];
```

The function `func` takes the cell contents, and creates a `Section` cell with the right structure. Then [`NotebookWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookWrite) replaces the old cell with this new cell. Finally, I move the insertion point to just the right place so that further typing will just add on to the content in the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox).

*DefaultFormatType*

The [`DefaultFormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultFormatType) for a `Section` cell is [`DefaultTextFormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultTextFormatType). Since I am creating a box structure from the contents of the `Section` cell I want to use [`DefaultInputFormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultInputFormatType) instead. If I use the default, then a `Section` cell with inline content could get mangled. With [`DefaultInputFormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultInputFormatType) the contents will just be an appropriate box representation of the original `Section` cell.

**Section**

The `ToExportedSection` style is what I want to point to in the [`StyleKeyMapping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleKeyMapping) for "Section":

```
Cell[StyleData["Section"],
    StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab" -> "ToExportedSection"}
]
```

**FromExport**

Earlier I mentioned that the [`StyleKeyMapping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleKeyMapping) for `ExportedSection` pointed to `FromExport` instead of `Section`. This is because I want to remove the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) when converting back, and so just like I needed a `ToExportedSection` style to add the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox), I need a `FromExport` style to strip the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox). However, in this case, the cell that is obtained by `NotebookRead @ EvaluationCell[]` has the necessary markup information to create the right kind of cell to convert to. Hence, I don't need a `FromExport` style for each style that I'm going to export.

***Usage***

Those are most of the issues in creating a stylesheet to enable simple creation of exportable styles, and the full stylesheet is given at the end of this answer. This stylesheet include exportable `Section`, `Subsection` and [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) styles.

The process of creating content using this style sheet is as simple as using the keyboard shortcut to create the style (e.g., <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd> to create the `Section` style), and then hit [`Tab`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tab) to convert to the `ExportedSection` style, and then type your section name. Similarly for the `Subsection` (<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd>) and [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) (<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd>) styles.

If you later want to edit the cell, you can just type as normal. If you happen to not be in the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox), you will find that your added content will be green and not the correct style color. In this case, just erase and move the cursor so that it is in the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) and try again. Here is a screenshot where text is added outside of the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox):

[image]

Hopefully the green color is a sufficient clue that text is not being added to the TemplateBox.

***Stylesheet***

Below is the stylesheet, given as a [`Notebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Notebook) expression assigned to the variable `nb`. You can either use:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions->nb]
```

in the notebook that you want to autogenerate a package from (remember to also use `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], AutogeneratedPackage->Automatic]` as well), or you can install the style sheet using:

```
NotebookPut @ nb
```

and then select `Install Stylesheet ...` and fill in the dialog to give the stylesheet a name and install it into your system. Then you would just select this stylesheet using the `Format | Stylesheet` menu item.

```
nb = Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Markup"],
        TemplateBoxOptions->{
            DisplayFunction->(StyleBox[
                #1,
                FontColor->CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions,#2,FontColor}],
                FontFamily->CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions,#2,FontFamily}]]&
            ),
            InterpretationFunction->(
                Cell[
                    TextData[{"(* ::", #2, ":: *)\n(*", Cell[BoxData[#]], "*)\n"}]
                ]&
            )
        }
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["Section"],
        StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"ToExportedSection"}
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["ExportedSection", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Section"]],
        StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"FromExport"},
        Evaluatable->True,
        System`InitializationGroup->True,
        Background->GrayLevel[.95],
        FontColor->RGBColor[0,.5,.0] (* to indicate text outside of template *)
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["ToExportedSection",StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Section"]],
        CellDynamicExpression :> With[
            {
            content = Replace[
                First @ NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]],
                BoxData[x_] :> x
            ]
            },

            NotebookWrite[
                EvaluationCell[],
                Cell[
                    BoxData @ TemplateBox[{content, "Section"}, "Markup"],
                    "ExportedSection"
                ],
                All
            ];
            SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],After,CellContents];
            SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Previous,Character]
        ],
        DefaultFormatType->DefaultInputFormatType
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["Subsection"],
        StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"ToExportedSubsection"}
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["ExportedSubsection", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Subsection"]],
        StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"FromExport"},
        Evaluatable->True,
        System`InitializationGroup->True,
        Background->GrayLevel[.95],
        FontColor->RGBColor[0,.5,.0] (* to indicate text outside of template *)
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["ToExportedSubsection",StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Subsection"]],
        CellDynamicExpression :> With[
            {
            content = Replace[
                First @ NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]],
                BoxData[x_] :> x
            ]
            },

            NotebookWrite[
                EvaluationCell[],
                Cell[
                    BoxData @ TemplateBox[{content, "Subsection"}, "Markup"],
                    "ExportedSubsection"
                ],
                All
            ];
            SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],After,CellContents];
            SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Previous,Character]
        ],
        DefaultFormatType->DefaultInputFormatType
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["Text"],
        StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"ToExportedText"}
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["ExportedText", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Text"]],
        StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"FromExport"},
        Evaluatable->True,
        System`InitializationGroup->True,
        Background->GrayLevel[.95],
        FontColor->RGBColor[0,.5,.0] (* to indicate text outside of template *)
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["ToExportedText",StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Text"]],
        CellDynamicExpression :> With[
            {
            content = Replace[
                First @ NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]],
                BoxData[x_] :> x
            ]
            },

            NotebookWrite[
                EvaluationCell[],
                Cell[
                    BoxData @ TemplateBox[{content, "Text"}, "Markup"],
                    "ExportedText"
                ],
                All
            ];
            SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],After,CellContents];
            SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Previous,Character]
        ],
        DefaultFormatType->DefaultInputFormatType
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["FromExport",StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Section"]],
        CellDynamicExpression :> With[
            {
            cell = Cases[
                First @ NotebookRead @ EvaluationCell[],
                TemplateBox[{a_, b_}, "Markup"] :> Cell[a, b],
                Infinity,
                1
            ]
            },

            NotebookWrite[
                EvaluationCell[],
                Replace[
                    cell,
                    {
                    {Cell[a_String, b_]} :> Cell[a, b],
                    {Cell[a_, b_]} :> Cell[BoxData[a], b]
                    }
                ],
                All
            ];
            SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],After,CellContents]
        ],
        DefaultFormatType->DefaultInputFormatType
    ]
    },
    StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
];
```

Comment: Cute. Definitely more extensible than using trick characters. No way you know of to access the actual front-end export functions, then? (slash way to trick the FE into thinking your current notebook is actually bound to a .m/.wl)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still hoping for a proper answer but here's the work-around I've been working with.

Since I use `IninitailizationGroup` my `"Section"`, `"Subsection"`, etc. cells are already tagged as being `InitializationCells` so I don't have to do anything there. They do, however, need to be made [`Evaluatable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluatable.html) to be exported to the package file.

They'll be exported as raw code, however, unless we hack the markdown in.

So what I did was set up a standard left and right character that would format the markdown and for each style I set

```
ExportAutoReplacements->{
 leftEscape->"(* ::"<>style<>":: *)\n(*",
 rightEscape->"*)"
 }
```

and

```
CellEventActions->{

{"MenuCommand","HandleShiftReturn"}:>
 With[{
   ev = CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], Evaluatable],
   text = First@NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]]
   },
  SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[],
   All,
   CellContents
   ];
  NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[],
   If[ev // TrueQ,
    StringTrim[text,
     (StartOfString ~~ (Whitespace | "") ~~ leftEscape) |
      (rightEscape ~~ (Whitespace | "") ~~ EndOfString)
     ],
    leftEscape <> text <> rightEscape
    ]
   ];
  SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], {
    Evaluatable -> Not@ev
    }];
  ]

}
```

This way I can easily toggle which markdown cells get exported and make sure they have the appropriate formatting.

Then there's the question of what to use for your `leftEscape` and `rightEscape` and unfortunately here I think there's no good choice. They obviously can't be the same and if you pass a multiple character string to `ExportAutoReplacements` it will treat each individual character as an instance for replacement which is not the desired behavior.

In the end I went with `leftEscape="\[LeftCeiling]"` and `rightEscape="\[RightFloor]"` because it's not too aesthetically displeasing and I doubt I will ever actually want to use either of them in my cell text.

And this works fine, even if it is hacky and unsatisfying. As an example here's the side-by-side comparison of my dev notebook and the formatted package:

[image: example]